# Git post-receive-email: Unknown type of (commit)

Tags: git, githooks

I'm having an issue with Git's post-receive-email hook script. Here is what I did:

1. On my server, I initialized a bare repository using: `git --bare init myrepo.git`. My server's Git config file says `core.bare = true`
2. Did the setup using the guides for Git email for post receive
3. On my client, clones the repository using `git clone URL`. On my client, Git config is `core.bare = false`.
4. Did some work, added the new files, committed to the local Git
5. Pushed the changes to the remote repository using: `git push origin master` which issues the generated ref-ids for the commits done
6. But I do not receive emails; so tried to run the post-receive hook script on the server in `hooks` directory with `./post-receive <oldrev> <newrev> refs/heads/master`

The following error is constantly returned:

> Unknown type of update to c9c047af (commit) 
>   no email generated

Any clues what could be wrong?

Comment: Well you're dying pretty early in the script so it should be easy to debug. What are you getting for `git rev-parse <oldrev>`, `git rev-parse <newrev>`, `git cat-file -t $(git rev-parse <oldrev>)` and `git cat-file -t $(git rev-parse <newrev>)`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I described the issue in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although I used a distribution `post-receive-email` script, I found a strange bug in the script. Towards the end of `post-receive-email` in my version said:

```
prep_for_email $2 $3 $1 && PAGER= generate_email
```

which should be

```
prep_for_email $1 $2 $3 && PAGER= generate_email
```

The change resolved my manual call to `post-receive <oldrev> <newrev> <refname>`. I hope this helps others that may face it.

Comment: I actually don't think it's the script that's buggy, but rather the instructions in post-receive.sample. Looks like it was outright removed about nine months ago, in 1.7.7 (commit 8d714b1). Gmane reference: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/182235

Comment: More importantly, did this actually fix your server? The invocation of that line is only when it's passed arguments. Comments in the script suggest it doesn't run this way when it's run as a server-side hook script, but I can't say for sure without a bit of experimentation.